# migrate products, categories, customers from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, migration, backup

How we can take backup from Magento 1.7.0.2 and restore in 1.9.0.1?

We need to take backup for

- Customers
- Products
- Categories

I only found some expensive extensions. I know that we can do it easily using database backup but this is in case of same Magento version. My question is, how can I migrate from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can import Customers,Products and Categories from csv.

- For customers and products , go to system > export/import.
- For category csv export you can use this one http://www.magentoworks.net/import_categories.zip

Comment: provided link doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take whole backup of magento 1.7 in some different place and follow the bellow steps . It will upgrade your store from 1.7 to 1.9 with same db

1. Take a backup of current database and current 1.7 code. place maintenance.flag file inside 1.7 code folder to put website offline.
2. Download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. Remove all folders and files from your 1.7 code except maintenance.flag (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.
4. Now from your 1.7 merge your following custom folders into the 1.9

   •   Community app/code/community

   •   Local app/code/local

   •   Media

   •   your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/ or app/design/frontend/)

   •   custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).

   •   copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/

   •    any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.

   •    copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.7) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).

   •    custom js files if any from app/js/.
5. Now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6. Remove maintenance.flag file and check the site in the browser. it is done.

Do not forget the encryption key of the old version. When upgrading the site to new installation, be sure to use the same Encryption Key.

Also you can follow magento's guidelines to upgrade store from one version to another.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Missed important steps in any upgrade: 1. Check for core hacks. 2. Check for core extended via local namespace. 3  check module compatibility 1.7 to q.9 is a big jump.vthere will be modukes tgat are not compatible.